# ¿Como puedo bajar la opacidad de un imagen de background desde 1 hasta 0 y volver desde 0 hasta 1 y así sucesivamente?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

```js
// find elements


var $window = $(window)
var $layer = $('#banner-message')
var $section = $('.section')

$(window).on('scroll', function() {




 var $windowScroll = $window.scrollTop()

 var $scroll = $windowScroll / 1000



  if ( $scroll <= 1 && $scroll > 0  ){

    var alphaBg = 1 - ( $windowScroll / 1000 )

     $layer.css('opacity', alphaBg)
    console.log('DEC',alphaBg);


   }else if ( $scroll > 1   ){

       var alphaBg = ( $windowScroll / 1000 ) -1

       $layer.css('opacity', alphaBg)
         console.log('INC',alphaBg);
    
   }





 });
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
 background: url('https://unsplash.it/1500/750?image=1041');
  width: 100%;
  height:600px;
   display: block;
  background-size: cover;
   z-index: -1;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   opacity: 1;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

.section{
  height:1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
 <div class="section"><</div>
 <div class="section"><</div>
 <div class="section"><</div>
</div>
```

Tengo una imagen de fundo en posicion fija... Cuando voy haciendo scroll me gustaria que esta imagen se va a bajar de opacidas desde 1 hasta 0 y despues siguiendo con el scroll desde 0 hasta 1 y así sucesivamente...

por ahora la imagen se baja desde 1 hasta 0 y vuelve desde 0 hasta 1, pero siguiendo va a salir mas de 1.

en este enlace esta una demo del mi codigo https://jsfiddle.net/ptrwymwL/

Gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres que el tamaño del body represente la opacidad? Es decir, ¿que cada píxel que bajas o subes mediante el scroll baje o suba la opacidad de la imagen?

Comment: No exactamente... me gustaria que se sigo con el scroll la opacidad se baja asta 0 y vuelve a subir hasta 1 y siguiendo asi.. hasta el final de la pantalla, en el fiddle ahora la imagen vuelve a mostrarse solo dos vez cuando yo necesito que se vuelve a mostrar por una tercera vez

Comment: Vale, osea, quieres que alterne la opacidad mientras usas el scroll.

Comment: Exactamente! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente tienes que cambiar la transparencia del fondo en el evento `'scroll'`. Te dejo un ejemplo muy sencillo sin imagen de fondo, adaptarlo a background-image es relativamente trivial:

```js
let toTransparent= true;
let opacity=1;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  if (toTransparent) {
    opacity-=0.01;
    if (opacity<0.01) {
      toTransparent=false;
    }
  } else {
    opacity+=0.01;
    if (opacity>0.99) {
      toTransparent=true;
    }
  }
  $('#d').css('background-color',`rgba(255,0,0,${opacity})`);
  
})
```

```css
div {
  height:500vh;
  width:50%;
  background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: Sí, pero creo que la idea es que al llegar al top o al bottom o sea transparente o sea sólido. Tal como está la opacidad puede quedar a medias cuando se llega al final o al inicio del contenedor.

Comment: Como comentaba @gugadev necesito que la imagen de fundo se mostrara 3 vezez, llega a ser transparente ( se cambiara imagen de fundo) i vuelve a ser solida... siguiendo asi por 3 vezez

Comment: Entonces hay que calcular el % de scroll y actual conforme a ese valor... a ver si tengo tiempo y lo miro esta tarde/noche

Comment: Muchas gracias @PabloLozano, esta imagen de fundo es como una imagen de portada por cada secion, abajo de la imagen ( cuando es trasparente ) tengo que hacer subir textos